# 遅延回答レビューで「稀に見る非常に優れた内容に注意」とは

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

遅延回答のレビューで

> これは、古い質問に対する新しいユーザーの回答です。稀に見る非常に優れた内容、答えになっていない回答、スパムに注意してください。

とありますが、「稀に見る非常に優れた内容」「に注意」とは具体的にどういうことなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

古い質問にはよくあるのは：

1. 「僕も同じ問題あります」のような回答じゃない投稿
2. スパム

たまに古い質問にいい回答がありますが、通常は上記のような投稿になるため、注意して判断したほうがいいと言う意味です。

Comment: So I should just take it in the most logical way. As @Myaku mentioned, the sentence seemed to be saying "Be on the lookout for (1) good answers, (2) answers that are not answers, and (3) spam", which is weird. If we were to suggest a different translation, should one just post it on Transifex, or would you suggest asking in meta before hand.

Comment: @packet0 if you want to translate, no need to ask on meta first. Give me your transifex username (if you aren't already a part of the group) and then start translating.

Comment: @packet0 ただTransifexで「レビュー済み」になっているフレーズはレビュワー（今のところモデレーターと社員）が解除しないと変更できないので、[チャット](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)等で一声かけて頂いて解除や修正を行っている感じです。今回の件については慌てることもないと思うので今私の方で反映することはしませんが、レビューは解除しておいたのでお好きなタイミングで更新していただければと思います。

Comment: @unarist ありがとうございます。とりあえずMyakuさんの訳が良さげだったので投稿しましたが、英語の原文的には元のほうが直訳ではあるんですよね...

Comment: @packet0 個人的には趣旨が伝われば、というか伝わるように変えてしまえばいいと考えています。それでも英語版やその雰囲気に慣れていると原文をなぞりたくなるんですが…ユーザーを増やしていく上でも、日本語のサイトとして伝わりやすい文章になっていた方がいいでしょう。

Answer (score 5):

jmacさんの回答を元に修正してみました。

> これは、古い質問に対する新しいユーザーの回答です。稀に見る非常に優れた内容の可能性もありますが、答えになっていない回答や、スパムでないか注意してください。

---

以前のものですと下記のような箇条書きで3つの内容に注意するよう受け取られてしまうかと思います。

> これは、古い質問に対する新しいユーザーの回答です。
>
> - 稀に見る非常に優れた内容
> - 答えになっていない回答
> - スパム
>
> に注意してください。

Comment: そうですね、とりあえず自分は「A,B,Cに注意」と思ってしまいました。transifexで変えれると思いますが、事前に1度別の質問で確認したほうがいいんでしょうか？